# Pythonic and concise way to construct this list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I write the following code more concisely?

```
    scores = []
    for f in glob.glob(path):
        score = read_score(f, Normalize = True)
        scores.append(score)
```

I know this can be written in one or two lines without using `append`, but I'm a Python newbie.

Comment: `scores = [read_score(f, Normalize = True) for f in glob.glob(path)]` - it's a list comprehension that does exactly the same model.

Comment: That's the classic usage scenario for [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Quick follow-up question: What if I want to sort the list of files that glob iterates over? It doesn't directly return a list but an iterable, so calling glob.glob(path).sort() gives an error. Can it still be done in one line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh, I got it while browsing a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830727/is-there-a-more-elegant-pythonic-way-to-express-this-construct):

```
scores = [read_score(f, normalize=True) for f in glob.glob(path)]
```

Comment: use: `sorted(glob.glob(path))`